# If r.v. A is independent of B and A is independent of C, can we say A is independent of (B, C)?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

I think the converse holds. To prove the claim in the question, I attempted as follows:

$$
P(A, B) = P(A)P(B)
$$
$$
\implies \sum_{C}{P(A, B, C)} = \sum_C{P(A, C)P(B)}
$$
$$
\implies \sum_C{P(A, B, C)} = \sum_C{P(A)P(B)P(C)}
$$

But that's as far as I could get. Does the claim in the question hold?